# Upload a file with navigator

Tags: php, html, ftp, file-transfer

I used to have a php script used to upload and download files to my server but the variable `max_upload_size` could not be larger than 50mb (due to some restrictions from the company which we contracted the service). Now I have to upload files up to 50mb so I had to explore other options. I discarted the option of having a dedicated server, because I have no idea of how to manage it. I have thought to make a button that points a direction: `ftp://user:password@ftp.domain.com` and upload and download files directly from that. The problem is that only in Internet Explorer you can upload files, not in Chrome, Firefox, etc. 
Could someone give me a solution of how to upload files using Chrome, or another way to do it?

EDIT: I also explored the option of making a batch file that opens the same uploading page but in Internet Explorer, executed through an `onClick()` but I learnt that it could not be possible due to security restrictions

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to help you much on this matter, but the way to avoid having problems with max_upload_size is to just send chunks.

Split any file you want to send into chunks of something like 10MB, send them where you want, but you have to reassemble them when they get there.

Comment: Yes, this was an other option but the users may not know a simple thing as it is making chunks of the file to upload it and reassembling the chunks when it is download.

Thank you for your answer

Comment: Just make a tool for them that receives the file for them, easy.